# How to display three digits before decimal and after decimal point six digits in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[image]

This is error it is taking any value it should table only this sequence **234.345456**

Comment: How about using a `decimal(9,6)`?

Comment: ya we can use decimal (9,6) i had column called longitude and latitude with data type like "Nvarchar". when user enter something like (23.23424432) ,(432423.343) this for should not take only this format should accept.(232.343244) please can you help me how to validate this/

Answer (score 0):

This is really simplified and there may be scenarios you have to tweak. `CHARINDEX` will find the decimal point. Then use `SUBSTRING` to pull out string. using the known charindex and string length.

```
DECLARE @lat DECIMAL(20, 10)= 541244.435123456

SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(CAST(@lat AS VARCHAR), CHARINDEX('.', @lat) -3, 10)
```

Comment: thanq @Chao.   actually i had column called longitude and latitude with data type like "Nvarchar". when user enter something like (23.23424432) ,(432423.343) this for should not take only this format should accept.(232.343244) please can you help me how to validate this.

Comment: @teja I don't understand. If it is already nvarchar the. Just take off the cast. I just added that because I didn't know the data type.

Comment: @Chao : for above code where i need to add validation

Comment: @ Chao :  CASE WHEN (CAST(A.GPS_LATITUDE AS NVARCHAR) IS NOT NULL AND CAST(A.GPS_LATITUDE AS NVARCHAR) <>'' AND CAST(A.GPS_LATITUDE AS NVARCHAR) NOT LIKE'%*%') AND ISNUMERIC(CAST(A.GPS_LATITUDE AS NVARCHAR)+'e0') = 0 OR (LEN(A.GPS_LATITUDE)>20) THEN 'Invalid Latitude. ' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN (CAST(A.GPS_LONGITUDE AS NVARCHAR) IS NOT NULL AND CAST(A.GPS_LONGITUDE AS NVARCHAR) <>'' AND CAST(A.GPS_LONGITUDE AS NVARCHAR) NOT LIKE'%*%') AND ISNUMERIC(CAST(A.GPS_LONGITUDE AS NVARCHAR)+'e0') = 0 OR (LEN(A.GPS_LONGITUDE)>20) THEN 'Invalid Longitude. ' ELSE '' END